# How to integrate the default g++ compiler with vscode?

Tags: compiling, g++

I installed Ubuntu 16.04LTS about a week ago. Also, I installed 'Visual Studio Code (VScode)' to do some c++ programming but I couldn't find any article on the Internet that explicitly explains how the setup process to integrate the g++ compiler to VScode is supposed to be done. Any instructions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The steps would:

1. Make sure `g++` is installed on your system.
2. Install `g++` vscode plugin.

   - Open VS Code.
   - Click the Extensions View icon on the Sidebar.
   - Search for c++.
   - Click Install, then click Reload., OR
3. Launch VS Code Quick Open (Ctrl+P), paste the following command, and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

   - `ext install ms-vscode.cpptools`

With that vscode should be able to compile and run your `c++` code.

Image:

[image]

More information:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/cpp

Comment: Couldn't find anything close to a "g++" plug-in to vscode.

Comment: Please follow step 3!